# List<String> Syntax error google script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I can't get my head around setting up an array in Google script (Which is based off Javascript).

I have a list of countries, 'AU' and 'NZ' that I need in the array, this will be added to later. I will need to search the array later to check if a string matches a value in the array.

I've tried adding the array several ways in Google script.

#### First attempt:

```
List<String> country_list = new ArrayList<String>();
country_list.add("AU");
country_list.add("NZ");
```

This Throws up a `Syntax error.` on the 1st line.

A variation on this:

#### Second attempt:

```
var country_list = [];
country_list.add("AU")
country_list.add("NZ")
```

Throws up the error `TypeError: Cannot find function add in object .` on the 2nd line.

#### Third attempt:

```
var Country_List = ["AU","NZ"];
if (country_list.contains("AU")) {
    // is valid
    ui.alert("great success");
} else {
    // not valid
    ui.alert('Nope try again');
}
```

This throws up an error 'TypeError: Cannot find function contains in object...'

That makes sense so I tried converting to `Array.asList()`.

#### Fourth attempt:

```
var original_country_list = ["AU","NZ"];
List<String> country_list = Arrays.asList(original_country_list)

if (country_list.contains("AU")) {
    // is valid
    ui.alert("great sucsess");
} else {
    // not valid
    ui.alert('Nah Mate try again');
}
```

This throws up the error `Invalid assignment left-hand side` when using `[]`  and `()` to hold `original_country_list`. When using `{}` to hold `original_country_list` it throws up the error `Missing : after property ID`.

The last thing I tried was:

#### Fifth attempt:

```
var original_country_list = ["AU","NZ"];
var country_list = Arrays.asList(original_country_list)
```

and this throws up the error `ReferenceError: "Arrays" is not defined`.

Apologies if this is obvious but what is going wrong here?

Comment: Are you talking about Google apps script? It is based on Javascript but not Java. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview.

Comment: Yes Google apps script, my mistake, updated to Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most of what I see here looks closer to Java than Javascript. But #2 can be Javascript like this:

```
var country_list = [];
country_list.push("AU");
country_list.push("NZ");
```

3 can be fixed easily too:

```
var Country_List = ["AU","NZ"];
if (Country_list.indexOf("AU") > -1) {
  // is valid
  ui.alert("great success");
 } else {
   // not valid
   ui.alert('Nope try again');
 }
```

Comment: These are both work great, Thanks, My confusion has been in using Java when GAS is Javascript based.